# Add sheet with successive number VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple macro, that adds a sheet to a workbook. However, sometimes I have to delete some sheet(s). When I delete a sheet and I use the macro again, the newly added sheet assumes the number which follows, as if the deleted sheets are stil present. I want that the macro adds a sheet with the next number. For example I have:

```
Sheet1 Sheet2 Sheet3
```

Then I delete `Sheet3` and want to add another sheet, which perfectly will be `Sheet3` and not `Sheet4`

```
With ThisWorkbook

    .Sheets.add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)

End With
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Off the top of my head, you would need to loop through the existing sheets to check their names, find the missing sheet in the iteration, and set the new name to that missing sheet. Then add the sheet as normal with "Name:=SheetName".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in the Workbook:
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)

    On Error GoTo Workbook_NewSheet_Error

    Sh.Name = "Sheet" & Sheets.Count

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

Workbook_NewSheet_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Workbook_NewSheet of VBA Document DieseArbeitsmappe"

End Sub
```

Pretty much, if you have a the following sheets `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` and `Sheet4` and you add a new one you would get an error, because the name of the sheet is taken (`Sheet4`). That is why I have added error handler.

Comment: This will only fill the gap if the deleted sheet is the last one in the iteration. If "Sheet3" is deleted and there are now 5 sheets, it will add "Sheet5" instead of "Sheet3".

Comment: @BrandonBarney - yup, it will do exactly so. But I understood that this is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: That may be the case and I can certainly be mistaken. I thought he simply wanted to use the next available number, and presumed that this wouldnt always be at the end of the count.

Comment: @Vityata thank you. this works. However I did not mention I have two other sheets before Sheet1. So I need that the macro starts at Sheet1 and continuies successivly. My mistake - sorry

Comment: You can always put 'sheet.count-2' in the code, @tombata.

Comment: Thank you very much